# Debugging graphql queries in Django

Tags: django, graphql

How can I get my GraphQL API to show more query/post data in the console? I'm running a Django app that is powered by GraphQL and served via a react frontend. With regular Django paths I would see something like this in the development server:

```
[04/Sep/2020 11:53:08] "GET /my_app/2020/09/01/5cc4e7cc-7.png HTTP/1.1" 200 11330
```

But with GraphQL all I see is this:

```
[04/Sep/2020 11:53:18] "POST /graphql HTTP/1.1" 200 32
[04/Sep/2020 11:53:18] "POST /graphql HTTP/1.1" 200 2993
[04/Sep/2020 11:53:29] "POST /graphql HTTP/1.1" 200 11635
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your query is passed as *payload* which will be processed by the graphql engine. All data are posted into a single end-point, (`/graphql` in your case)

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest checking out [Silky](https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk). It's a profiling tool that can show you

1. the request body - that's where you'll find the graphql
2. speed of the response
3. all the DB queries sent during your request
4. (if you set it up) cprofiler for the request
   [image: example query audit]